# how to sort street addresses in Angular / Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a couple street addresses

```
10 E. Main Street
1 E. Main Street
2 E. Main Street
```

When I do an orderBy (with ng-repeat) they come out

```
1 E. Main Street
10 E. Main Street
2 E. Main Street
```

How can I get them to come out as

```
1 E. Main Street
2 E. Main Street
10 E. Main Street
```

EDIT:

```
   <th ng-click="reverse = (sort=='date' ? !reverse : false); sort = 'date'"><a href='#' >Date</a></th>
   <th ng-click="reverse = (sort=='address' ? !reverse : false); sort = 'address'"><a href='#' >Address</a></th>
   <th ng-click="reverse = (sort=='message' ? !reverse : false); sort = 'message'"><a href='#' >Hazard</a></th>
```

custom loop

```
<tr ng-repeat="address in ctrl.addresses | orderBy: (sort=='address' ? addressSort() : sort) : reverse">
```

and in my controller

```
        this.addressSort = function(streetAddress){
            return parseInt(streetAddress.split(' ')[0]);
        }
```

The reverse sort logic works for both date and message, but I can only get the decending sort for the address.

Comment: angular is sorting these values as strings.  unless you can separate the address into a numeric and non-numeric compliment, you'll have to write your own sorting function.

Comment: @Claies A custom message mostly worked, but now I can't get reverse sorting to work properly

Comment: I would recommend using a natural-sorting library that can handle the sorting of various different elements.  There are a few JavaScript natural-sort libraries available, for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-natural-sort

Comment: the way you are trying to do it now, you will have issues if you have multiple alphabetical street names with the same street number.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for the look at natural sort, however that's a node package, and I'm not using node.

Comment: it's not a node package, it's just a javascript sort function.  if you aren't using npm, you can just browse to the github page for it (https://github.com/Bill4Time/javascript-natural-sort) and download the javascript source directly.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you have with alphanumeric characters, your options are limited. No framework can solve this.

If you have a object structure with house number in one property and then street address in another property. You can apply sorting on each property.

Since you asked angular, create a separate filter and then can apply on ng-repeat.

We can help in writing that code if you need.
Cheers.

Comment: Please see the edit to the question.  I've already tried doing custom coding and the reverse functionality now fails

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var addresses = ["10 E. Main Street", "1 E. Main Street", "2 E. Main Street"];

addresses.sort(function(a, b) {
    var numA = a.split(" ")[0];
    var numB = b.split(" ")[0];
    return numA - numB;
});
```

The callback function inside the sort method, checks for the first word on the array, and returns a value to be ordered. (a negative number for `a` to be first, and a positive number for `b` to be first.

[here is the docs for the sort method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)